# Refresh select list after a first select list

Tags: javascript, c#

I can't refresh the second select list after I have selected an option in the first select list. I am using javascript and nothing on the web works.
How I can refresh or activate the second list AFTER i have choose an item in the first list ?

```
     <div class="editor">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.ResponsibilityCategory
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="ResponsibilityCategoryId" name="ResponsibilityCategoryId" msr-default=@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.All msr-read="JsonList/ResponsibilityCategory" class="msr-select" msr-default="@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.All"   msr-value="ResponsibilityCategoryId" msr-text="ShortDescription" style="width:300px"   onchange="FilterResponsabilitiesByCategoryResponsabilities()"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="editor">
<div class="editor-label">
                @Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.ResponsibilityCategory
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<select id="ResponsibilityCategoryId" name="ResponsibilityCategoryId" msr-    default=@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.All msr-   read="JsonList/ResponsibilityCategory" class="msr-select" msr-  default="@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.All"   msr-   value="ResponsibilityCategoryId" msr-text="ShortDescription" style="width:300px"   onchange="FilterResponsabilitiesByCategoryResponsabilities()"></select>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="editor">
        <div class="editor-label">@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.Responsibility</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="ResponsibilityId"  name="ResponsibilityId" class="msr-select" msr-default=@Resources.Report.MetaAssignedResponsabilities.All style="width: 700px">
@{
                 var list = db.Responsibility.ToList().Select(o => new { o.ResponsibilityId, o.LongDescription }).OrderBy(w => w.LongDescription);
                    if (resp == "nothing")
                    {
                        foreach (var p in list)
                        {
                    <option>@p.LongDescription</option> 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] split = resp.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
                        foreach (string s in split)
                        {
                            var list2 = list.Where(w => w.ResponsibilityId == Convert.ToInt32(s));
                            foreach (var p in list2)
                            {
                    <option>@p.LongDescription</option> 
                                                 }
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function FilterResponsabilitiesByCategoryResponsabilities() {
    debugger;
    var s = $("#ResponsibilityCategoryId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    s = s == "" ? 0 : s;

    switch (s) {
        case "1":
            s = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
            break;
        case "2":
            s = "7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14";
            break;
        case "3":
            s = "15,16,17,18,19,20,21";
            break;
        case "4":
            s = "22,23,24,25,66";
            break;
        case "5":
            s = "28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,59,60,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80";
            break;
        default: s = "0";
    }
```

Comment: C# code runs on the server, javascript code runs on the local machine.  If you want the drop down to change on the local machine then the javascript must look at the DYNAMIC value of the dropdown not the value when the page is loaded.

Comment: Yes but the dynamic value is set after I choose something in the first select list. Or the second list is loaded when the page is loaded. Actually the second list is set with a variable that change when I choose something in the first list.

Comment: yes -- that is why you have to write the code in javascript to run in the browser not c#

Comment: Ok, I will try something, thank you.

Comment: You will have to either refresh the page (POST your form) when the user changes the first select, or use Ajax to refresh it without reloading the whole page.